# Lucene ignores / overwrite fuzzy edit distance in QueryParser

Tags: lucene

Given the following QueryParser with a FuzzySearch term in the query string:

```
fun fuzzyquery() {
    val query = QueryParser("term", GermanAnalyzer()).parse("field:search~4")
    println(query)
}
```

The resulting Query will actually have this representation:

```
field:search~2
```

So, the `~4` gets rewritten to `~2`. I traced the code down to the following implementation:

**QueryParserBase**

```java
protected Query newFuzzyQuery(Term term, float minimumSimilarity, int prefixLength) {
    String text = term.text();
    int numEdits = FuzzyQuery.floatToEdits(minimumSimilarity, text.codePointCount(0, text.length()));
    return new FuzzyQuery(term, numEdits, prefixLength);
}
```

**FuzzyQuery**

```java
public static int floatToEdits(float minimumSimilarity, int termLen) {
    if (minimumSimilarity >= 1.0F) {
        return (int)Math.min(minimumSimilarity, 2.0F);
    } else {
        return minimumSimilarity == 0.0F ? 0 : Math.min((int)((1.0D - (double)minimumSimilarity) * (double)termLen), 2);
    }
}
```

As is clearly visible, any value higher than 2 will always get reset to `2`. Why is this and how can I correctly get the fuzzy edit distance I want into the query parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may cross the border into "not an answer" - but it is too long for a comment (or a few comments):

***Why is this?***

That was a design decision, it would seem. It's mentioned in the documentation [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fuzzy_Searches).

> *"The value is between 0 and 2"*

There is an old article [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search#a-simple-fuzzy-match) which gives an explanation:

> *"Larger differences are far more expensive to compute efficiently and are not processed by Lucene."*.

I don't know how official that is, however.

More officially, from the JavaDoc for the [`FuzzyQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html) class, it states:

> *"At most, this query will match terms up to 2 edits. Higher distances (especially with transpositions enabled), are generally not useful and will match a significant amount of the term dictionary."*

***How can I correctly get the fuzzy edit distance I want into the query parser?***

You cannot, unless you customize the source code.

The best (least worst?) alternative, I think, is probably the one mentioned in the above referenced `FuzzyQuery` Javadoc:

> *"If you really want this, consider using an n-gram indexing technique (such as the SpellChecker in the suggest module) instead."*

In this case, one price to be paid will be a potentially much larger index - and even then, n-grams are not really equivalent to edit distances. I don't know if this would meet your needs.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer. I also found this while researching further